# Are there pyramids at Sternenfels?

Tags: archaeology, pyramids, germanic, skeptical

The author Frederick Dodson in his rather strange book "[Extraterrestrial Linguistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B096WCNZM6)" (2020) makes the claim that several pyramids have been excavated in the German town of [Sternenfels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternenfels). I have been unable to find any reliable source to confirm this, though there are mentions on what appear to be amateur / crank websites in both English and German. I haven't found any counter claims, either, which suggests the pyramid notion may be a niche one.

Dodson's photographs show some stone walls that one assumes are genuine and possibly ancient, but I can't see anything that proves they were part of a pyramidal structure.

Are these mysterious "pyramids" real or just something concocted by cranks?

Comment: His Goodreads bio refers to him as a "success coach and consciousness researcher", and says he also wrote a book called "The Reality Creation Technique". One suspects him of using "reality creation techniques" when he came up with that assertion.

Comment: Why the tag 'germanic'? Is Dodson claiming that as well? (If so, please include a direct quote from that book for that here).

Comment: @LаngLаngС that was my probably incorrect use of the tag. I'll remove it if it's unhelpful.

Comment: Unsure: Probably your choice. But I guess Dodson aims at anything 'really ancient' with -lithic in the name? (And still others _do_ claim 'Germanic' or even 'German' origin, to… prove something…) Something stone age would of course contradict 'germanic' immediately, so it might mostly depend on what this author writes? (Adding his claims about the alleged timeframe would be plus anyway… )

Comment: This might be a better fit for the skeptics stack exchange.

Comment: @LаngLаngС his book repeats a claim by Erhard Landmann that ancient German is both the origin of all human tongues, and alien in origin, so I guess the pyramids are Germanic in that sense, but others who believe in the Pyramids don't quite go so far in their kookiness. I just wanted to mark the question as being about Pyramids located in Germany rather than in Egypt.

Comment: Reality is sometimes disappointing, but writing that book put a smile upon his face.

Comment: Did you ask Google Earth, for instance?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Updated answer gives you the link to the place and some of its sights.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Jolly good, and why does that not help Alfred Armstrong? What does it leave unclear?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin if you are asking why a search on Google Earth would not answer the question, Dodson doesn't claim there are pyramids still standing at Sternenfels, just the remains of them. It's the identification of what definitely can be found there, various piles of stones etc, as part of former pyramids that's the contentious element.

Comment: @lang indeed. Similarly, while megalithic structures in the British isles are often popularly associated with Celtic civilizations, they actually predate the arrival of Celtic peoples by thousands of years.

Comment: I’m sorry this needs to be pointed out, and clearly it does: the wording ‘Are these mysterious "pyramids" real or just something concocted by cranks?’ makes itself unanswerable, because that’s the way English works.

Your links lead to marketing information about Dodson’s book, and to a travel guide about Sternenfels.

Why not include a link to Dodson's photographs, showing the stone walls assumed to be genuine and possibly ancient, whether or not you see anything proving they were part of a pyramidal structure?

More…

Comment: Further… Your language is broadly the kind used by conspiracy theorists, making almost everything questionable and almost nothing capable of confirmation.

Before that, how clear it is that 'several pyramids have been excavated in the German town of Sternenfels' is the main part of Dodson’s claim? I suggest the wording is yours.

The real question is much more simple: ‘Are there really "pyramids" or not?’

More…

Comment: Further… Sorry, and to ask about ‘… these mysterious "pyramids”…’ is to state that those pyramids are real. Whether they’re mysterious is a valid question but in your words, ‘… these mysterious "pyramids” ’ exist.

The difference between your wording and mine is that between speculation and science, fantasy and a search for fact.

When you’ve been unable to find a reliable source, why would we put that down to a lack of sources, rather than the limitations of the searches you didn’t specify? Why not specify what searches you made?

More…

Comment: Further… When there are mentions on what appear to be amateur / crank websites in English and German, how are you defining “amateur / crank”? Are they the same? Did you find six or 30 or 204 “amateur / crank” sites, or how many of each?

Did you notice, counter claims would prolly be posted only by people interested - which you seem to suggest no-one should be?

Don't you think whether the pyramid notion is a niche one has little to do with whether it’s real? Consider Minoa or Troy, for comparison.

Sorry to care, and I do.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin as I indicated the (poor quality) photographs don't show anything that looks like a pyramid. There's better pictures at https://pyramiden-deutschland.de/die-zwerchhaelde-von-sternenfels/. Feel free to post an answer if you have one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are certainly no 'pyramids' at Sternenfels. There are some man-made alterations to the landscape, but while they are claimed sometimes to be pre-historical, most available reliable info indicates those traces to be of historical time origin from this area, when it was being used as a quarry. Note that the 'pyramid'-theories claim this to be 'a pyramid within a quarry'.

The village [Sternenfels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternenfels) — translated: 'Star Rock' — is said to more or less openly 'encode' its 'pyramid past' in its coat-of-arms:

[image]

Looks like a ziggurat or step-pyramid?

Of course, the 'modern' version is based on the coat-of-arms of the local nobility, more or less in the form just shown since *1684* (offical for the village since 1964), and giving the whole village the name of the noble family that itself was named after its the new [castle Sternenfels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burg_Sternenfels), after calling themselves previously: ~'Lords of [Kürnbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCrnbach)'.

Slight problem for this 'pyramid in coat-of-arms' explanation: the noble [family Sternenfels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternenfels_(Adelsgeschlecht)) has used this version:

[image]

among [other variations](https://www.heraldik-wiki.de/wiki/Felsen_%28Heraldik%29), sometimes clearly 'natural rocks', sometimes in the more man-made looking, previously called *Fels* (rock) version, which now is in heraldry uniformly called *[Stufengiebel](https://www.heraldik-wiki.de/wiki/Stufengiebel_(Heraldik))* ([stepped gable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepped_gable)).

Now, the official archaeological explanation for the structures found is that these are remnants of the local, previously quite productive *quarry.* For *[Stubensandstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenstein_Formation),* used among other things for building the name-sake castle… The village itself explains its [historical roots as quarry supplier since Roman times](https://www.sternenfels.org/index.php?id=439).

And an amateur, 'private', 'archaeologist' uses an official map of the area called *'Zwerchhälde'* (which might be translated as ~little or 'Dwarf' heap) to add his own explanations for the geological features found:

[image] [image]

For those inclined to look it is found via [via Google Earth: coordinates 8.83975,49.05305000000001,0](https://earth.google.com/web/@49.05255939,8.83965768,356.34122185a,0d,35y,-0.0000h,45.0000t,0.0002r/data=ChAqDggBEgoyMDA4LTEyLTMx?) or [GMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Keltenruine+und+Ausgrabungsst%C3%A4tte/@49.0536864,8.8394706,3a,75y/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNEB2g_-MSgCZIExJBbJLQBRb5eCF_I51uCZPrP!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNEB2g_-MSgCZIExJBbJLQBRb5eCF_I51uCZPrP%3Dw360-h480-k-no!7i3000!8i4000!4m5!3m4!1s0x47979dd438521edd:0x26cea6f5ea525972!8m2!3d49.0536864!4d8.8394706) where the spot is called "Celtic Ruins and Excavation site", with some pictures. Another [round of pictures taken 2013](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/111385414011867440849/album/AF1QipP2taLlpamR-z3bsmW4XFFlO6peRDKeIpS91SWz?feat=embedwebsite&authKey=CMiUss6ksafD2gE), and a [video showing the powertool excavator of that 'pyramid initiative' (self-title_ "IG Pyramide Sternenfels", which claims this to be a cairn…) in action (~10 minutes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqAl078HWFk)…

Although this 'K Walter Haug' ([project website of this 'citizen scientist'](https://www.megalith-pyramiden.de/home-2/zwerchhaelde.html), who likes to dig with other amateurs dowsers and [excavators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excavator)) likes to describe this not as pyramid at all, but a 'Cairn' ([WP-link-to-word-meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairn), [src1](https://pyramiden-deutschland.de/die-zwerchhaelde-von-sternenfels/), [src2](http://www.godeweg.de/10_9_sternenfels/Sternenfels_Walter_Haug.html)). *If* there is anything pre-historic in the surroundings of this site, various amateurs, treasure hunters and ordinary gold diggers seem bound to damage or destroy any possible future finds in that regard. ([Petition to the local mayor of the village detailing some fights](https://secure.avaaz.org/community_petitions/en/Burgermeisterin_und_Gemeinderat_von_Sternenfels_Grabungsverbot_d_Zwerchhalde_aufheben_Walter_Haug_als_Sprecher_anerkenne/) over who gets to do what on that mount indicate: 1. some unprofessional digs and destruction already in advanced progress, 2. either 'unfortunate' or 'convenient' 'disappearance' of 'evidence'…)

The so far apparently only one picture of that site that made it to Wikimedia Commons:

> [image]
>
> — ["Fassade der Zwerchhälde Sternenfels Detail"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zwerchhaelde_Mauerfassade_Detail.jpg)

To [quote proponents of this outlandish theory to speak for themselves:](http://www.godeweg.de/10_9_sternenfels/Sternenfels_Walter_Haug.html)

> Now no one can deny the buildings and dismiss them as profane spoil heaps in quarries. From the very beginning, the walls and passage portals were recognizable to everyone. Now whole sections of walls of colossal height, steps, stairs and the stairway to a portal are exposed, which, however, is massively hidden by enormous walls.
>
> That is the peculiar and at the same time fascinating thing: Our highly cultural buildings are largely hidden in ancient quarries. There are various phases of subsequent use, which is why archaeologists are unable to recognize the original conception at first glance. But unfortunately they could not bring themselves to a detailed study of these constructions until today. In fact, they have not invested a single minute of work until today. Everything remained with the discoverer.
>
> So our work is pure private research. We do not receive any support from the state. We finance our budget through donations, book sales and lectures. IG Pyramide Sternenfels, founded in May 2011, is therefore an ideal association without any commercial purpose.
>
> Since our step pyramids and cairns (the technical term used in Europe for this type of prehistoric structures) are located in quarries, they are not recognized by the Provincial Archaeology of Baden-Württemberg. The enormous structures, one could call them in German also Kärner (ossuary), are officially considered as walled spoil heaps! Geological explorations, however, may be carried out by anyone in quarries.
>
> We have the big problem that our numerous discoveries and excavation results are not acknowledged by the academic world.

We know it was a quarry, 'they' know it was a quarry, and 'they' even say so. Walls and steps and spoil heaps do not necessarily make a cairn, but could be explained with necessity reasons within the quarry operation. Evidence for the claim is thin or lacking entirely.

Comment: Thanks, that's amazingly clear and helpful. I suspected something was very fishy about the claim but I prefer not to dismiss things out of hand without checking.

Comment: You might be interested to learn, by the way, that Dodson reckons the "Zwerchhalde" (as he gives it) is so-called because "Space-Dwarves" used to land their spacecraft there!

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Yooo. That aspect sounds like a wonderful icebreaker for doobie-us conversational evenings if topics like the 'symbols on the dollar bill'-theme is exhausted?

Comment: Ah, but the Ancients devised that pyramid *inside* the solid rock and all the quarriers did was remove the rock that wasn't the pyramid, revealing their Ancient's whatsit in all its splendor. Amazing!

Comment: Would be significantly improved without the scare quotes. Dry wit relies on understatement.

Comment: Note that naturally formed [pyramid-shaped mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_peak) are not uncommon.  The examples list on that page doesn't show any for Germany, but nearby Austria and Switzerland are both listed (and I don't think that list is exhaustive).